# Confusion with city/country when bringing database to third normal form

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization

I'm trying to normalize a table and bring it in the third-normal-form, but I'm confused about this case:

Take this simple table:

```
stores
-------

id   name   type    city    country
```

Is `country` transitively dependent on `id` via `city`? I rushed to say yes, but then I thought the a city with the same name might exist on another country. Does that mean this table is in 3rd normal form, or is there something that needs to be amended?

Comment: There's not much value in asking others to guess what dependencies might apply just based on a list attribute names. The point of normalization is that you have a *known* set of dependencies that ought to hold true in your particular domain and that you want to implement in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  You're right, `country` doesn't depend on `city` (e.g. 'Paris' isn't sufficient to determine the country - is it France or Texas, USA?)

The city column on its own doesn't represent the domain we want to relate, but if the combination of city and country does then I would consider `(city, country)` to be a composite value, similar to how a date is a composite of `(day, month, year)`.  That would mean the relation is in 3NF having 3 FDs: `id->name`, `id->type` and `id->(city,country)`, since the dependency `(city,country)->country` is considered trivial.  Practically, I would consider introducing a surrogate key in this case.

If the combination of city and country isn't unique, then we still have a 3NF table with FDs `id->name`, `id->type`, `id->city` and `id->country` and no dependency between the last two.

Comment: Depending on how you look at it, there may also be cases where a single city straddles a border and so is located in more than one country.

Comment: Indeed, and cases where (city, country) isn't unique either, e.g. Beverly Hills, CA and Beverly Hills, TX are both in the USA.  Different sources may have different definitions or boundaries for any given city, and things get even messier if we consider time.  Bill Kent's book `Data and Reality` is a great exploration of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say city and country need a separate table. Think that cities can change their name (India is still renaming cities: Bombay to Mombai happened years ago but it seems that this is still happening). Also Scotland recently had a referendum to remove themselves from the UK; they voted 'stay', but the issue seems far from over.

So I'd put city/country in a separate table. I might even put them in two separate tables, but unless you had some functionality (e.g. tax calculations) dependant on the country I'd probably stick to one.

Comment: I would do the same but this doesn't address the question.

Comment: I agree with you answer above, but would add that without knowing some details of the domain no definitive answer is possible. Does Country have a meaning in the domain or is it just a part-identifier for Cities? For example, if a Sales Tax calc is part of the domain then Country is a separate entity with Sales Tax rules attached; if not then maybe we're fine as is.